# passwordLastSet and password expired soon for each language and then send an email

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Today my ideas it was extract some user with the password expired soon and then send an email in each language .

```
 $files=(Get-ChildItem "$HOME\script\expire\").FullName
    $send=@{
    to = "administrator@corp.internal"
    from = "administrator@corp.internal"
    Subject = "US" 
    Attachment = $files
    SmtpServer = "10.10.10.10"
    }

    $French=@{
    to = "administrator@corp.internal"
    from = "administrator@corp.internal"
    Subject = "FR"
    Attachments = $files
    SmtpServer = "10.10.10.10"}

    $AU=@{
    to = "administrator@corp.internal"
    from = "administrator@corp.internal"
    Subject = "AU"
    Attachments = $files
    SmtpServer = "10.10.10.10"}

    Get-AdUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False -and PasswordLastSet -gt 0 } -Verbose -Properties DisplayName, PasswordLastSet, Mail, Office -SearchBase "OU=Test,OU=CORP,DC=corp,DC=internal" -Server "10.10.10.1" | Where-Object {
            $_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays(30).Date -eq ((Get-Date).AddDays(30).Date)
        }  |ForEach-Object -Verbose {


    $bodyreset=
    @"
    I delete real message because it was to big and I don't have any issue to receive these mail
    "@

        if ( $_.office -like "FR*")
        {
       Send-MailMessage -Body "$bodyreset"  -BodyAsHtml @french
       }elseif($_.office -like "US*")
       {
       Send-MailMessage -Body "$bodyreset"  -BodyAsHtml  @send
       }
       else{
      Send-MailMessage -Body "$bodyreset"  -BodyAsHtml @AU
        }
     }
```

I own 29 000 users on my virtual server and the user was created in the same days .

I am looking to some help to understand why the script don't send 29 000 email ,indeed I received arround 14 000 email .

i can saw this error after 14 885 mail has been send at the same address .

```
Send-MailMessage : Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: 4.4.1 Connection timed out
At line:82 char:3
+   Send-MailMessage -Body "$bodyreset"  -BodyAsHtml @AU
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage

Send-MailMessage : Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: 4.4.1 Connection timed out
At line:82 char:3
+   Send-MailMessage -Body "$bodyreset"  -BodyAsHtml @AU
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

I tried to export in CSV file and I can see 29 000  users ,thank you `.count`

can you help me to understand ,where I am wrong .

Comment: You don't think the mail server admin might have put rate limits in place to stop people from doing what you're trying to do: flooding the system with messages? Try adding a delay, or at least send the mails in smaller bursts. Or talk to your mail admin about whitelisting your sending host.

Comment: I am the owner of both server  and didn't have enable the security but i will check . I found https://technet.microsoft.com/en-en/library/exchange-online-protection-limits.aspx and your are right .I never thinking about a security from microsoft exchange because I send mail message from Active Directory server .

Comment: I will try to fix it by this 
`If (((Get-Content "$HOME\testc.txt").count) -eq "10000"){
write "breaks"
sleep -Seconds 380 } `
I try to store in `$t=
@"
"@
$t+="a`n"` but does not work with count